# Null pointer exception is thrown even though identical handler works normally

Tags: java

I am very new to java. I'm trying to build a simple application in JavaFX, but something very odd is happening: I have two nearly identical handlers, `handleButtonAction` and `handleButtonAction2` and two labels, `clicked` and `selected`. I have one button. When I set this button to use `handleButtonAction` everything works. When I switch to `handleButtonAction2` I get a null pointer exception. I really can't understand this as to my eyes both handlers do virtually the same thing.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label clicked;
    private Label selected;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Text1");
        clicked.setText("Text2");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction2(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("More Text1");
        selected.setText("More Text2");
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Anyone can shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: Well one has an `@FXML` annotation and the other doesn't...

Comment: You don't even say what's null.

Comment: @DaveNewton Based on what he said, specifically that `handleButtonAction2` is where the NPE is thrown, `selected` is tossing an NPE.  And, as shmosel pointed out, `clicked` is marked with the `@FXML` annotation but `selected` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FXMLDocumentController.selected instance must be null. You probably forgot to initialize it, when you have class instances the compiler or IDE usually doesn't warn you about the instance not being initialized (Or at least, mine doesn't). Check your other classes for the mistakes, if you really can't find it. Post the code from your other classes here too.
Edit: I'm stupid for not realising this, I believe you have to do this:

```
@FXML
private Label clicked,selected;
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted self-answer on behalf of the question author)*.

I really thought one @FXML annotation above was enough. Thanks for the polite answers and being tolerant of my stupidity.